# Cardinality of the intersection of two Sylow p-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Suppose $p$ is a prime and $a, b, m$ are positive integers such that $(p, m)=1, 1 <m < p^b<p^a$. For a group $G$ of order $p^am$ together with a non-normal Sylow $p$-subgroup $H$, prove that there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup $K \neq H $ which satisfies $| K \cap H| \geq p^{a-b}$.

I've been attempting to find a suffciently large subgroup $A$ of $H$ such that the normalizer $N_G(A) \supsetneqq N_G(H)$, hence the *Second Sylow Theorem* can be used to end the proof. Not sure if I am on the right way, thanks for any help!

Comment: Let $H,K$ be distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups, and consider the order of the product $|HK| = |H|K|/|H \cap K|$.

Comment: This is neat, and I didn't see that coming! Thank you a lot!